# What software can be used for interactive viewing of huge images (JPG &PNG) on Windows?

Tags: windows, zoom, image-viewer, high-resolution

By interactive, I mean the software should provide capability to pan/zoom parts of the images just like how Google Maps are displayed.

I have some very large images (with resolution more than 10000x15000).

Typical image viewers load images entirely in memory, but for very large images zooming/viewing of specific portions is required.

[Vliv](http://delhoume.frederic.free.fr/vliv.htm) is one such software but it only support TIFF format.

**Update: Although not exactly a desktop software, [Panojs](http://code.google.com/p/panojs/) is a perfect fit for above purpose. One need to create a HTML web app (which can used locally as well as deployed on a webserver).**

Comment: Try Deep Zoom. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645050(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Check this one out: http://www.fastpictureviewer.com/

Comment: There is a web app called Zoom.it that works quite well for this.

Comment: You do realize that Google Maps doesn't work like this?

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it, the other answers clearly didn't answer this question